# Gridgain Control Center

Tags: ignite, gridgain

After a recent upgrade of the gridgain control center , we lose cluster info and credentials everytime the pod restarts.
Our gridgain control center backend is a deployment and not a stateful set and we were using persistent volumes to save the state.
Can someone help me understand how/where the cluster and credentials are stored in the control center. This will help us debug the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the backend you need a persistent volume for `/opt/gridgain-control-center/work`. Using a stateful set is a good idea here.